# Which is the correct distribution to use?

Tags: openlayers, deployment

I wanted to know that if the pre-build js of OpenLayers-3 available at http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/build/ol.js is self-sufficient or does it need to use the internet for any of its functioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to the [Releases page](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases) of OpenLayers 3, and download the latest Distribution.

At the time of writing this, the latest version is 3.4.0, and the distribution is [available here](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/download/v3.4.0/v3.4.0-dist.zip).

For development you should use the ol-debug.js, and in your production, you should use the ol.js file.

Comment: ok i got those. So do these satisfy the criteria i mentioned?

Comment: Yes, they have no dependencies on online resources.